# Analyzing and avoiding a Full GC in Java

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I'm working on a time critical application with a time cap of 40 ms per iteration. If the time cap is exceeded just once, the application is terminated and game over. The application itself has no problems staying under the 40 ms mark, it's the garbage collector that exceeds the limit sometimes.

Using an object pool combined with the factory pattern, I managed to mostly eliminate the need for garbage collection and the application achieves a steady 17 ms iteration time including small GC runs, except that between 10 and 20 iterations after application start just one single full GC occurs that exceeds 40 ms and kills my application.

My question is, how can I analyze what exactly is causing this one full GC? I used jvisualvm intensively to profile my runtimes and my memory footprint and it was a great help identifying the objects that I need to cache. But in this particular case I cannot use it, because the full GC occurs long before I can press the right buttons in jvisualvm. **Is there a way to generate a heap dump programatically?**

Comment: Java is a bad choice for time critical apps. However, there are special VMs dealing somewhat better with that situation

Comment: You might have to look at real-time JVMs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a choice. It has to be Java with a standard JVM.

Comment: Sorry, than failed to match language and requirements. It is like driving with the car to moon

Comment: If your requirement is (a) 40ms guarantee with the hard constraint you suggest above; and (b) must use a general purpose JVM, then you have an overconstrained problem.  You can't do both.  Suggest you have a second look at your requirements and constraints.  RT Java is the right way to go if you're determined to do it in the Java space, at it can work well.  The answers below are great hints to decreasing the *probability* of a deadline miss, but are inadequate by far to provide a guarantee.

Comment: I need constructive suggestions please. The language and the JVM are not changable. Not even garbage collection tuning or heap size parameters are allowed. But since after overcoming the singe full GC after start up the application runs reliably, I think the requirement can be met just fine after understanding and eliminating thefirst full GC.

Comment: @Marcell:  You're running a race against long experience...  which is OK, and you may well get to a deadline miss rate that works for you, but it will be a delicate and fragile balance, and predicated in observed behavior only in the specific contexts you test in.  If you can tolerate that, OK.

Comment: @Marcell: you'd better add all the extra info about not changing language, vm, or any other params to the question to avoid having answers suggesting to change all of the above or the layer between the monitor and the chair.

Comment: If you can't even change the VM parameters, then, if you have any professional responsibility, you should tell your employer/customer/evil alien overlord that this problem cannot be solved.

Comment: For the programmatic heap dump generation; throw an OutOfMemoryError in the code, and give JVM -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError option.

Comment: I think I formulated my question very clearly. It was how to analyze why the full GC happens. Thanks to all who suggested actual approaches to this problem.

Comment: If you want good GC cycles, you might want to completely avoid object creation / destruction. Just create whatever mutable objects you need at the start of the program and you should be fine if the GC has nothing to do. You could also try using G1.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a commercial memory profiler like YourKit. You can get a free eval license from most of these long enough to solve your problem. ;)

A problem I have found with VisualVM is that when you minimise your object creation, the biggest memory producers is the Memory Profiler itself. The commercial profilers don't have this problem as they use off heap memory.

I would see what you can do about reducing your garbage further. 17 ms is still a long time, you might consider CPU profiling this as well. CPU profilers are useful down to about half a ms. For lower than that you need to use precise timing of your own and some trial and error.

Something I have found useful is after doing a CPU profile and a Memory profile, run them both at once and you get more suggestions as to what you can improve.

If you reduce the amount of garbage you produce and increase you eden space you might be able to only get a minor collection once per day.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-avoid-garbage-collection.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak; [Try this link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mat.ui.help/tasks/acquiringheapdump.html)

or Alternatively using

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=<filename.hprof> <pid>
```

Comment: No I haven't. My keyboard doesn't have a Break key. :( But I can try this on an another PC.

Comment: Try alternative of Ctrl + / I believe.

Comment: Using jmap will also be difficult, because I only have a fraction of a second to find out the pid and type in the command. It would be best to programatically create a heap dump before the full GC and after to see what changed.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage Collection on the JVM is a huge advantage most of the time but the major downside (as you have identified) is that it sometimes causes unpredicatble GC pauses.

The standard JVM is OK for soft realtime (when you can tolerate an occasional pause) but not a good fit for hard realtime (i.e. when any pause beyond a given tolerance causes an error/failure)

Some helpful advice would be:

- Move to specialised realtime JVM if you can (e.g. the [Zing JVM](http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zing/virtual-machine)). This is the best way to reliably get realtime behaviour with Java
- Use low latency libarries e.g. [Javolution](http://javolution.org/) - these can help a lot by providing data structures with very low rates of object allocation (and hence less GC overhead)

Answer (score 1):

You can try an evaluation version of [jprofiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), it lets you make the app wait for the profiler to start. It does not affect heap memory, and it is a powerful profiler in general, with good IDE integration and one-click set-up.

But since you say you can not control heap size or gc settings, there's not much you'll be able to do. Loading classes at startup creates some garbage that needs to be collected.

Might I ask: is this homework or just some kind of a contest/challenge?

Comment: Yes, it is for a contest. Even if I can't change the gc settings, analyzing the heap can help me to find out what exactly is garbage collected and get hints as to where to optimize my code.

Comment: @Marcel: have you tried jprofiler? it looks like it is the tool you need.

Comment: @Marcel: as a random thought, since you have about 30ms to spare, you might intentionally add some `sleep()` to let young gc clean up stuff before sending it to eden or survival.

Comment: I'm running jprofiler right now. It is better than jvisualvm in the sense that it can launch the application right out of the profiler and allows me to take a glimpse at the heap after start up. There are a lot of ArrayList Iterators on there which disappear and never come back (get garbage collected?), so I assume that's what the problem is. However, I cannot see them in the heap walker so I can't trace them back to a specific class where they came from.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tuning the garbage collection parameters?  If you're on a machine with enough RAM and more than one core then you should be able to take advantage of parallel garbage collection.  It's [enabled by default on Java 1.6 JVMs](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/6_performance.html#2.2.1).  Basically, if you ensure the young generation is big enough so that objects never get promoted to the old gen (which is collected in serial).